# progressbar and Data loading

Tags: c#, datagridview, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i have Windows Form in C# having Datagridview with large no. of records from database and some comboboxes,textbox and buttons.

so,i used another form having progressbar and backgroundworker so that data loading of mainform does not iritate enduser.

```
 public partial class FirstForm : Form
{
    MainForm mf;
    public FirstForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        mf = new MainForm(); //inside constructor,code of data loading in gridview
        mf.Update();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (p1.Value < p1.Maximum)         //p1 name for progressbar
            p1.Value++;
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Hide();
            mf.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

but when main form is displayed,it is blank and after 2/3 seconds datagridview and other controls appear.

how to solve this..?
or suggest other ideas to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your code in Firstform and write mine in 
programs.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        MainForm = new MainForm(); // creating main form
```

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            frm.Inittiate(); // Add this method to first form to loading and initiating

```
        bw.CancelAsync(); // ending splashing
        Application.Run(frm);
}     

static void bw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    AFirstForm splashForm = new FirstForm();
    splashForm.TopMost = true;
    splashForm.Show();
    while (!(sender as System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending)
    {
        splashForm.Refresh();
    }
    splashForm.Close();    
    e.Result = splashForm;
}
```